# uninitialised value(s) valgrind

Tags: c, arrays, valgrind

When running valgrind, I'm getting a `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` message.

I've allocated a pointer to struct array, and I think it has something to do with this array.

```
struct nlist **hashtab;

void init(void)
{
    hashtab = malloc(HASHSIZE * sizeof(*hashtab));
}
```

Valgrind message:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes bin/Zuul

==3131== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3131==    at 0x400EF4: lookup (Dictionary.c:42)
==3131==    by 0x400DDE: install (Dictionary.c:18)
==3131==    by 0x4009A6: createItems (Game.c:42)
==3131==    by 0x400901: main (Game.c:19)
==3131==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3131==    at 0x4C2757B: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3131==    by 0x400DB9: init (Dictionary.c:9)
==3131==    by 0x4008FC: main (Game.c:16)
```

`install()` is the first function called from `createItems()`, which is using `hashtab`:

```
struct nlist *install(char *name, listItem *_item)
{
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;

    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) {
        np = malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdupl(name)) == NULL)
            return NULL;

        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        np->_obj = _item;
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    }
    else
        free((void *) np->_obj);

    return np;
}
```

The lookup function:

```
/* lookup: look for s in hashtab */
struct nlist *lookup(char *s)
{
    struct nlist *np;

    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
            return np;

    return NULL;
}
```

Displaying the value of `hashtab` in ddd after `init()`:
[image: Value of hashtab, displayed in ddd]

Comment: Is Dictionary.c:42 the strcmp line in lookup()? And you should also test `s` and `np->name` for non-NULL values, since that's what `strcmp()` expects (valid strings)

Comment: @grasbueschel Yes, line 42 in Dictionary.c is the call to `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind is correct. You never initialize your hash table after allocation. You allocate the memory, but `malloc()` makes no guarantees of the allocated *content* (thus your pointers are all *indeterminate*).

One possible approach to doing this, change `init()` to this:

```
void init(void)
{
    hashtab = malloc(HASHSIZE * sizeof(*hashtab));
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<HASHSIZE; hashtab[i++] = NULL);
}
```

Or another:

```
void init(void)
{
    hashtab = calloc(HASHSIZE, sizeof(*hashtab));
}
```

though the purists will say zero-filled does not equate to NULL filled.